# Why doesn't my mouseOver functions work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, mouseover

The game is quite simple you click on the start button to begin then move your mouse along the track until you reach the end then the timer stops and shows you the score. If you go out of the track you get a score of zero.

**Why don't my mouseOver functions work?**
Link to my full code: http://www.codecademy.com/TictacTactic/codebits/AQBK4L/edit

Thank you in advance!

```
var score = 1000;
var timer = setInterval(countDown(), 1000);

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#start').click(function() {
    $('#game').mouseover(function() {
        stopTimer();
        score = 0
        $('#points').html(score)
    });
    $('#end').mouseover(function() {
        stopTimer()
        $('#points').html(score)
});
});
});
function countDown() {
score = score - 1;
}

function stopTimer() {
clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: `mouseOver != mouseover`, there lies the problem.

Comment: why people does not post relevant code?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most events are in lowercase, like `mouseover`, `mouseout` etc. There are also others that have capitals, like `DOMContentLoaded`. Most (if not all) programming languages are case-sensitive, watch out for these.

Comment: It's seems  the score resets to zero whenever I hover off of the start button. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var clicked = false;

$('#start').click(function() {
    if(!clicked){
        clicked = true;         
    }
});

$("#game").hover(function(){
    if(clicked){
        stopTimer();
        score = 0;
        $("#points").html(score);
    }
});
$("#end").hover(function(){
    if(clicked){
        stopTimer();
        $("#points").html(score);
    }
});
```

Then later if you don't want the hover event to work just set clicked to false I.E : clicked = false;

Comment: Very good idea I was looking for an off switch idea but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried your code again. When I replaced hover with mouse over it worked but when I added 
score = 1000;
$("#points").html(score); 
so that the score goes back to 1000 when clicked it didn't work

Comment: Ah ok, well, I thought of the off switch because I wasn't sure if the hover event would exactly work.